# Most efficient unification algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, efficiency, formal-methods, unification

I've been trying to find the most efficient unification algorithm by following reference chains on [the Wikipedia article on unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#A_unification_algorithm). As far as I can tell, the fastest one is the one presented in ["A Practical Unification Algorithm"](ftp://ftp.cs.indiana.edu/pub/techreports/TR242.pdf), but is there a faster one?